# Why os library can not know whether this is a file or not?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, file, operating-system

I have a problem with **os** library, `isfile()` function and `isdir()` function returns false if I give it a file in another folder or folder in another folder too.

#### Here is the tree:

```
 Parent Folder┐         
              │
              │
              │ 
              ├─Nice Folder┐
              │            │    
              │            │    
              │            ├─Very Nice Folder┐
              │            │                 ├─Very very nice file.txt
              │            │                 
              │            ├─Very nice file.txt                            
              │
              ├─Nice file.txt                            
              │ 
              ├─Nice file2.txt  
              │
              ├─Nice file3.txt  
              │ 
              ├─Python File.py
```

**os** library can only get to know **[`Nice Folder`, `Nice file.txt`, `Nice file2.txt`, `Nice file3.txt`]**, but when it comes to what inside the **Nice Folder** returns false.

***I'm using Linux btw.***

#### Here is the code:

```py
import os

WD: str = os.getcwd()

files: list[str] = []
dirs: list[str] = []

def filter(path = os.getcwd()):
    
    temp_files: list[str] = []
    temp_dirs: list[str] = []

    for element in os.listdir(path=path):

        if element == "thecode.py" or element == "help.txt" or element == "thanks.py":
            continue

        if os.path.isfile(element):
            temp_files.append(element)

        if os.path.isdir(element):
            temp_dirs.append(element)

    if temp_dirs != []:
            
        for i in range(len(temp_files)):
            files.append(temp_files[i])

        for i in range(len(temp_dirs)):
            dirs.append(temp_dirs[i])

        for i in range(len(temp_dirs)):
            filter(os.path.join(WD, temp_dirs[i]))
            
        return dirs, files
    
    print(files)
    print(dirs)
    return temp_dirs, temp_files 

filter()
```

THANKS FOR HELP.♥

I tried to search for the cause of the problem but I did not get a solution, I looked at YouTube for similar problems, without use.
**I wanted to make him get to know all the files inside these Folders**.

Comment: You need to include the directory name: `os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, element))`